# Why PESSIMISTIC.WRITE in spring-boot JPA not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot jpa. I had to perform "select for update" in one of the query through jpa. My DB is SQL Server. I got to know that JPA supports OPTIMISTIC and PESSIMISTIC LOCKING. I tried the following in the jpa but it is not working

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("SELECT status from table  WHERE id = ?1 ")
 Integer getOrderStatusById(Long id);
```

I tested it by stoping the flow in the transaction(by adding the debug point) where this query is getting called and from the sqlserver server when I was trying to access the same record I was able to access it and was able to update the record as well.
Don't have any idea why its is happening? Am I missing something ?
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Can you please share the error log for the issue?

Comment: One more point to add. If in the query I am using the updlock jpa throwing error like updlock unknown keyword

Comment: @DhavalSimaria: Not getting any error just locking not happening as expected

Comment: Where are the transaction boundaries ? (Can you share the whole calling code and the line where you put the break point)

Comment: //@Transactional
 //@Override
  public void updateOrderStatus(RequestMetaData requestMetaData, Integer newStatus,
      Long id ){Integer status = jparepository.getOrderStatusById(fulfillOrderId); Sop(status);} I kept the debug point on the sop statement.

Comment: You aren't starting a transaction at the repository level aren't you ?